# How to simulate rolls that transport a metal sheet upwards in Blender Game Engine?

Tags: game-engine, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I am trying to get a metal sheet to move upwards using two pairs of rolls
please see [Blender File](https://github.com/eugenschindler/stackexchange/blob/master/TransportMetalSheetUp.blend?raw=true) for an example.
However, I cannot succeed to actually grip the sheet with the two rolls.

The sheet is configured as a soft body and the rolls are rigid bodies.

When I leave a little bit of room between the sheet and rolls, the sheet just falls down because of gravity.

When I move the rolls closer together, so they touch the sheet, then things get unstable and the sheet flies out of the viewport.

Is it possible to get the physics parameters right for this or is this not the right way to go at all and should I try something different?

Comment: I will try some things and if you made a breakthrough I will let you know

Comment: That would be greatly appreciated!